I have to trigger a local notification when user reaches in monitored region

I have to send local notification in iOS when user reaches at his nearby destination stored in local data

I have to trigger notification on did enter region method of clLocationManager delegate

it should trigger even if app is killed

I'm monitoring 20 regions near user's last location when user killed the app

like if user enters in monitored region it should automatically through a local notification
 func generateSurroundingRegions(currentLocation: CLLocation) {
     // Clear previous regions
     regions.removeAll()

     for i in 1...100 {
         // Generate random angle and distance
         let angle = Double(arc4random_uniform(360)) * Double.pi / 180
         let distance = Double(arc4random_uniform(1000) + 20) // between 200 and 1200 meters

         // Calculate the new region's center
         let newLatitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude + (distance / 111000) * cos(angle)
         let newLongitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude + (distance / (111000 * cos(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude * Double.pi / 180))) * sin(angle)

         let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLatitude, longitude: newLongitude), radius: 50, identifier: "Region\(i)")
         regions.append(region)
     }
 }


 func updateMonitoredRegions(currentLocation: CLLocation) {
     let sortedRegions = regions.sorted {
         let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: $0.center.latitude, longitude: $0.center.longitude)
         let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: $1.center.latitude, longitude: $1.center.longitude)
         return currentLocation.distance(from: location1) < currentLocation.distance(from: location2)
     }

     let closestRegions = Array(sortedRegions.prefix(20))
     let newMonitoredRegions = Set(closestRegions)

     for region in monitoredRegions.subtracting(newMonitoredRegions) {
         locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
     }



for region in newMonitoredRegions.subtracting(monitoredRegions) {
     region.notifyOnEntry = true
     region.notifyOnExit = true
     locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
 }

 monitoredRegions = newMonitoredRegions

}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return }
     lastLocation = currentLocation
     generateSurroundingRegions(currentLocation: currentLocation)
     updateMonitoredRegions(currentLocation: currentLocation)

 }



    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
     sendNotification()
     print("Entered region: \(region.identifier)")
    }




@workingdogsupportUkraine here is the code i think it's fine I don't know what I'm missing it's just not working for me

Do you have "always" location permission? Have you added the location background mode to your app?  Does it work when you don't terminate the app?

@Paulw11 I have

it's started working for me  I just added asking notification permission in app delegate
